# Database Each table Usage

Tags: 7, database

Where can I see the each table usage, which is getting created in default installation of a **Drupal** site.

Likes **node** table - `used to store all nodes in them`. For other tables where i can get the information. Any documentation for each table usage in database??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For databases that implement information schema, use:

```sql
SELECT table_name, table_comment 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema='my_cdrupal_database'
```

Answer (score 2):

Run below query on your database and see last column in the result table.

```sql
SHOW TABLE STATUS
```

See Screenshot below for example.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to add the Drupal-y answer...

You can install the [Schema module](https://drupal.org/project/schema) for that, amongst its features is:

> Schema documentation: hyperlinked display of the schema's embedded documentation explaining what each table and field is for.

Comment: Totally forgot about that. I guess because it was always faster for me to just look at schema in db client.

Comment: i don't want schema.I want each table description and looks like schema module doesn't provide me with that.

Comment: Did you read the description in the answer? That's exactly what it does